# SignUp Button redirecting to the MainActivity automatically instead of [SigninActivity through Intent]

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an Android app. I worked on sign-in and signup activities. I have different activities for sign-in and signup and have one main activity. Now, when initially I connected the Firebase database with the project and implemented the signup things it worked fine (just showed an dialogue and toast as I wanted). but when I have added sign-in using email/password and with Google also. After that when I looked on signup it started to behave strangely. First, it just shows the Toast and dialogue I had set on the onComplete() of Signup, but now it is also redirecting to the main activity. After I observed that I had put an intent redirecting to the Sign-in activity. Then from sign-in if successful user is redirected to the main activity. But now it's behavior is not what I wanted on sign up button, it redirects to mainactivity but I want to move to signin activity.

here is the code on sign-up button.

```
signUpBinding.buttonSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //show progress dialogue
            progressDialog.show();

            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                    signUpBinding.textEmailsignup.getText().toString(),
                    signUpBinding.textPasswordsignup.getText().toString())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,
                                        SignInActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                                //using Users constructor for signup
                                Users users = new Users(
                                        signUpBinding.textUsernameSignUp.getText().toString(),
                                        signUpBinding.textEmailsignup.getText().toString(),
                                        signUpBinding.textPasswordsignup.getText().toString()
                                );

                               
                                //to get the UID of user from AuthResult
                                String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                                //setting values in realtime database
                                firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").
                                        //we can use id and username or anyother string as we
                                        // want in the below child to name the user node.
                                        child(signUpBinding.textUsernameSignUp.getText().toString())
                                        .setValue(users);


                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User Created Successfully ",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Error: "+task.getException()
                                                .getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });


        }
    });
```

and this is the logcat on click of signup button

```
{2023-09-04 15:36:43.710 31698-31698 AppTurboService         com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D   getSettingSupport resullt = false mSettingCloudEnable = true
2023-09-04 15:36:43.752 31698-31698 ViewRootIm...g Account] com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2023-09-04 15:36:43.724 31698-31698 chatty                  com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  uid=10376(com.sarmadali.chatmingle) identical 2 lines
2023-09-04 15:36:43.724 31698-31698 AppTurboService         com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D   getSettingSupport resullt = false mSettingCloudEnable = true
2023-09-04 15:36:43.757 31698-31698 InputTransport          com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  Create ARC handle: 0x75177e3ce0
2023-09-04 15:36:43.758 31698-31698 FirebaseAuth            com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  Creating user with dgjkkbhgh@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
2023-09-04 15:36:43.776 31698-32101 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-09-04 15:36:43.781 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::connect(this=0x7517854000,api=1)
2023-09-04 15:36:43.782 31698-31734 mali_winsys             com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2023-09-04 15:36:43.782 31698-32101 System                  com.sarmadali.chatmingle             W  Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2023-09-04 15:36:43.782 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x7517854000,bufferCount=3)
2023-09-04 15:36:43.783 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7517854000)
2023-09-04 15:36:43.795 31698-32101 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [okhttp]:check permission begin!
2023-09-04 15:36:43.796 31698-32101 System                  com.sarmadali.chatmingle             W  ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
2023-09-04 15:36:43.798 31698-32101 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
2023-09-04 15:36:44.460 31698-32101 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [socket]:check permission begin!
2023-09-04 15:36:44.461 31698-32101 System                  com.sarmadali.chatmingle             W  ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
2023-09-04 15:36:44.464 31698-32101 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
2023-09-04 15:36:46.041 31698-32101 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
2023-09-04 15:36:47.520 31698-32101 System                  com.sarmadali.chatmingle             W  Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2023-09-04 15:36:47.538 31698-32101 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [okhttp]:check permission begin!
2023-09-04 15:36:47.539 31698-32101 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [okhttp]:not MMS!
2023-09-04 15:36:47.539 31698-32101 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [okhttp]:not Email!
2023-09-04 15:36:47.544 31698-32101 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
2023-09-04 15:36:48.398 31698-32101 FirebaseAuth            com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Notifying id token listeners about user ( ikasJsyb4saAFiS0hYVE1Mcggjh2 ).
2023-09-04 15:36:48.399 31698-32101 FirebaseAuth            com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Notifying auth state listeners about user ( ikasJsyb4saAFiS0hYVE1Mcggjh2 ).
2023-09-04 15:36:48.420 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::disconnect(this=0x7517854000,api=1)
2023-09-04 15:36:48.424 31698-31698 View                    com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@b4df957[Creating Account]
2023-09-04 15:36:48.425 31698-31698 InputTransport          com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  Destroy ARC handle: 0x75177e3ce0
2023-09-04 15:36:48.504 31698-31698 ViewRootImpl[Toast]     com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2023-09-04 15:36:48.509 31698-31698 InputTransport          com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  Create ARC handle: 0x74b9ec3400
2023-09-04 15:36:48.522 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::connect(this=0x7517854000,api=1)
2023-09-04 15:36:48.523 31698-31734 mali_winsys             com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2023-09-04 15:36:48.523 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x7517854000,bufferCount=3)
2023-09-04 15:36:48.523 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7517854000)
2023-09-04 15:36:48.531 31698-31698 ActivityThread          com.sarmadali.chatmingle             W  handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@c3e4fba
2023-09-04 15:36:48.532 31698-32113 libMEOW                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  applied 1 plugins for [com.sarmadali.chatmingle]:
2023-09-04 15:36:48.532 31698-32113 libMEOW                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D    plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
2023-09-04 15:36:48.537 31698-31698 os.typeface             com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Already set agent. fontPath:null fontHash:
2023-09-04 15:36:48.644 31698-31698 ActivityThread          com.sarmadali.chatmingle             W  handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@1e1f34
2023-09-04 15:36:48.645 31698-32115 libMEOW                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  applied 1 plugins for [com.sarmadali.chatmingle]:
2023-09-04 15:36:48.645 31698-32115 libMEOW                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D    plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
2023-09-04 15:36:48.649 31698-31698 os.typeface             com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Already set agent. fontPath:null fontHash:
2023-09-04 15:36:48.750 31698-31698 PhoneWindow             com.sarmadali.chatmingle             V  DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@7397a32[]
2023-09-04 15:36:48.753 31698-31698 ViewRootIm...nActivity] com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
2023-09-04 15:36:48.757 31698-31698 InputTransport          com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  Create ARC handle: 0x74b9ec3c00
2023-09-04 15:36:48.758 31698-31698 PhoneWindow             com.sarmadali.chatmingle             V  DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@2ce4539, this = DecorView@7397a32[MainActivity]
2023-09-04 15:36:48.759 28996-18468 MagicButtonManager      com.transsion.videocallenhancer      E  gained class = com.sarmadali.chatmingle.MainActivity
2023-09-04 15:36:48.784 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::connect(this=0x74ba05f000,api=1)
2023-09-04 15:36:48.786 31698-31734 mali_winsys             com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2023-09-04 15:36:48.786 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x74ba05f000,bufferCount=3)
2023-09-04 15:36:48.786 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x74ba05f000)
2023-09-04 15:36:48.826 31698-31698 IInputConnectionWrapper com.sarmadali.chatmingle             W  requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
2023-09-04 15:36:49.126 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::disconnect(this=0x74b9dde000,api=1)
2023-09-04 15:36:49.143 31698-31698 PhoneWindow             com.sarmadali.chatmingle             V  DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@ac646c5, this = DecorView@657b90e[SignUpActivity]
2023-09-04 15:36:49.151 31698-31698 View                    com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@657b90e[SignUpActivity]
2023-09-04 15:36:49.151 31698-31698 InputTransport          com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  Destroy ARC handle: 0x75106723e0
2023-09-04 15:36:49.650 31698-32110 System.out              com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  [socket]:check permission begin!
2023-09-04 15:36:50.491 31698-31734 Surface                 com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  Surface::disconnect(this=0x7517854000,api=1)
2023-09-04 15:36:50.493 31698-31698 View                    com.sarmadali.chatmingle             D  [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.LinearLayout{1366271 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-371,72}
2023-09-04 15:36:50.494 31698-31698 InputTransport          com.sarmadali.chatmingle             I  Destroy ARC handle: 0x74b9ec3400
}
```

Comment: As I can see you are already redirecting to `SignInActivity.class` when it’s successful. So u want navigate to the `MainActivity` as well is that your question?

Comment: Make sure your SignInActvity is not navigating to MainActivty directly in onCreate. Secondly, debug if the signUp task is successful or not. Use breakpoints.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved I have this code in onCreate() of SignInActivity .....    // if user is already login then start with mainActivity
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

Comment: @A.Gun Yes I want to be redirected to '''SignInActivity.class''' but it is not redirecting to it problem is that.

Comment: if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null), This condition returns true as you have completed signup in the previous activity and firebaseAuth has a user aginst it.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved yes, but on Logout button I have this code, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(); so it means it is not working?

Comment: The logout button is present in menu of mainactivity it is menu item. Where I implemented that code of logout.

Comment: can you share what result you are getting for `if(task.isSuccessful())`

Comment: Share a sample code if you can. One thing, You have no need to redirect the user to SignIn after SignUp.

Comment: @A.Gun the result of if(task.isSuccessful()) is success/true. Everytime I sign up the data is move to authentication in firebase and to realtime database.

Comment: Check the answer I have posted.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved You are right! if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null), This condition returns true as I have completed signup in the previous activity and firebaseAuth has a user against it, but now I have commented that part of code it works fine but it don't mainactivity if the user was already logged in. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: if (itemId == R.id.logout) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } .......... This is the code on the logout item. If we are logging out then if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null) it should return null. One thing to note is (itemId == R.id.logout) this code is in mainActivity and (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null) is in SignActivity.

Comment: Make sure SignInActivity as a launcher activity. If user is not logged in, He can go to signup activity for registration. On successful registration navigate user to Main Activity instead of SignIn activity. And on logout navigate user to SignIn activity. Uncomment that code. Just rearrange the activities.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved Yes I have already set SignInActivity as a launcher activity. (1) In case the user is not already logged in he will stay in SignInActivity to sign in or can go to the signup activity to register, then After registering it goes to the main activity instead of SignInActivity, I don't want the user to get to main activity directly after signup. (2) Now when I have set it up to Auth Activity it works fine. We can say at this moment our issue is resolved but in the sign-in Activity why if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null) always returning true.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved I have created an Auth Activity where the user can verify the code. Now on Sign up, I am moving the user to the Auth Activity, and it works fine. (I haven't implemented Auth Activity just created an empty activity). As I said earlier problem is with this  { ... if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)...} code in SignIn Activity.

Comment: UPDATE:  CurrentUser: null ... this is the result on debugging { ... if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)...}....  Log.w("User","CurrentUser:  "+ firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()); ..... If user is already logged in it returns user name if not it return null. So it means problem is not here.

Comment: CORRECTION: try {
            Log.d("CurrentUser","CurrentUser: "+ firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("CurrentUser","Failed: "+e);
        } .... I have tried this apporach outside the { ... if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)...} ... Now when i am logging out and moving to signinactivity it says Null Pointer Exception which is understandable, when user is already logged in it gives the user name. This is fine. Now its the same problem on sign up redirecting to mainActivity.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved your statement: if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null), This condition returns true as you have completed signup in the previous activity and firebaseAuth has a user aginst it... is absolutely correct. Now the question is how to prevent the new user that has just signed up from going to mainactivity?

Comment: Why do you need to prevent new users from navigating to MainActvity? 
However, if you still want to achieve this, You can signout user after createUserWithEmailAndPassword success listener. And then redirect it to SignInActivity.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved PLEASE HAVE A LOOK AT THIS QUESTION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77058090/when-logging-in-with-fake-template-email-app-crashes-and-when-logging-in-with-ac

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove if(task.isSuccessful()) phrase.
So it will be like this

```
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        

                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,
                                    SignInActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                            //using Users constructor for signup
                            Users users = new Users(
                                    signUpBinding.textUsernameSignUp.getText().toString(),
                                    signUpBinding.textEmailsignup.getText().toString(),
                                    signUpBinding.textPasswordsignup.getText().toString()
                            );

                           
                            //to get the UID of user from AuthResult
                            String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                            //setting values in realtime database
                            firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").
                                    //we can use id and username or anyother string as we
                                    // want in the below child to name the user node.
                                    child(signUpBinding.textUsernameSignUp.getText().toString())
                                    .setValue(users);


                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User Created Successfully ",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        
                    }
```

Comment: same output as it was.

Comment: Let me try it after cleaning and rebuilding and uninstalling app. We might have different results.

Comment: this isn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Navigating and finishing activity once all the execution done.

```
        signUpBinding.buttonSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //show progress dialogue
            progressDialog.show();

            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                signUpBinding.textEmailsignup.getText().toString(),
                signUpBinding.textPasswordsignup.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                //using Users constructor for signup
                                Users users = new Users(
                                    signUpBinding.textUsernameSignUp.getText().toString(),
                                    signUpBinding.textEmailsignup.getText().toString(),
                                    signUpBinding.textPasswordsignup.getText().toString()
                                );


                                //to get the UID of user from AuthResult
                                String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                                //setting values in realtime database
                                firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").
                                    //we can use id and username or anyother string as we
                                    // want in the below child to name the user node.
                                child(signUpBinding.textUsernameSignUp.getText().toString())
                                    .setValue(users);


                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User Created Successfully ",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Error: "+task.getException()
                                    .getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });


        }
    });
```

Comment: it gives the same output. But when I comment on the intent part it just shows the Toast as in the condition. It means problem is in the SignActivity has been mentioned by Abdullah Javed in the above comment section.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I was unable to understand the statement of @AbdullahJaved that

> if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null) [in SignInActivity], This
> condition returns true as you have completed signup in the previous
> activity and firebaseAuth has a user against it.

But After I tried to debug using below code in onCreate of SignInActivity

> try {
> Log.d("CurrentUser","CurrentUser Sign Activity: "+ firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
> }catch (Exception e){
> Log.d("CurrentUser","Failed Sign Activity: "+e);
> }

I have realized that the current user it is getting is the one that I have just signed up with, by matching the UserId of that user from Logcat and Firebase. So when it is being directed to SignInActivity from SignUpActivity the below code is returning true because we just have signed up and Firebase has a user against the CurrentUser, hence why it was being redirected to the MainActivity.

> > if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null) {Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
> > startActivity(intent);
> > finish(); }

So technically code is correct and behaving normally according to the instructions. But unfortunately, I was not getting it Why it is happening?

When I asked ChatGpt how to prevent the new user who has just signed up from going to the main activity?

The solution to this question according to ChatGpt is to implement a user authentication and authorization system which I have not done so far. (There might be another solution that i don't know of).

Details from ChatGpt are as follows:

**Authentication:** Implement a user registration and login system. You can use Firebase Authentication or your own backend server for this purpose. Ensure that users can only access the app's main functionality after they have successfully registered and logged in.

**User Profile Management:** When a new user signs up, store their user information in a user profile on your backend server or in a local database. You may also want to include a flag or attribute in the user profile to indicate whether the user is a new user or has completed some initial setup.

**MainActivity Logic:** In your MainActivity, check whether the user is authenticated and authorized to access the main functionality. You can do this by verifying the user's login status and checking their user profile attributes. If the user is not authorized (e.g., because they are a new user), you can redirect them to another activity, such as an onboarding activity or a profile setup activity.