# When Logging in with fake/template email app crashes and when logging in with actual google email it doesn't crash

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a Firebase database where I have stored the credentials through signup and Google sign-in. When I am signing in through real Google email it goes smoothly and also it doesn't show the current user in the recyclerView list. However, when I try to log in through the fake/template email that I used to sign up (haven't implemented any verification so far that's why able to sign up through the fake ones) - and password of that account then app crashes and it closes. when i see the logcat it says this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            

Process: com.sarmadali.chatmingle, PID: 13483
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.sarmadali.chatmingle.Fragments.ChatsFragment$1.onDataChange(ChatsFragment.java:74)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7684)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

and the null object which it is referring is caused by this:

```
String currentUserName = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
 //to not add current user in the list
//users is the Model
                    if (!currentUserName.equals(users.getUserName())){
                        list.add(users);
                    }
```

My first concern is that when I was signing in with the Google account it didn't through NullPointerException and when I logged in with the fake emails and passwords that are actually in the real-time database it throughs the NullPointerException, and hence it crashed the app.

I have also applied this:

```
Log.d("Current UserName","UserName: "+currentUserName);
```

As a result that i noticed that when logged in with the Google account it returns the username, but when I try to log in with the fake credentials (means that the email actually doesn't exist but I have set the username, email, and password through signup) Now these credentials are also in the firebase database, - it crashes the app and when I re-launched the app from my physical device the logs display username as empty not as null.
it shows the main activity(only allowed after login) and it includes the current user in the RecyclerView List as well. means it ignores that code when I again launch the app. Doesn't really get it why? because it is null? then it should crash again?

```
//to not add current user in the list
                    if (!currentUserName.equals(users.getUserName())){
                        list.add(users);
                    }
```

**It is the complete code of setting data on recyclerview and excluding the current user.**

```
reference = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                list.clear();

                String currentUserName = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                    Log.d("Current UserName","UserName: "+currentUserName);

                    //to not add current user in the list
                    if (!currentUserName.equals(users.getUserName())){
                        list.add(users);
                    }

                }

                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

If you need any other information ask me.

**UPDATE**

```
 Log.d("User ID","UserID: "+users.getUserId());
```

I have tried this and changed the comparison from userName to userId.
As a result of the above Log, I have got to know that now, the current user ID is always being displayed when it is the fake one and the Other user's ID is null. and due to this reason it is ignoring to exclude the current user from the list. And some times it shows the ids of other users too that of the real google accounts.

> users.getUserId()

doesn't seem to get the user id for all the user, don't know why?

I changed some code

```
if (users.getUserId() != null){
         Log.d("User ID","UserID: "+users.getUserId());
  //to not add current user in the list
           if (!currentUserId.equals(users.getUserId())){
                        list.add(users);
                    }
               }
```

From the above code i just getting the current user id from the below code not others.

> users.getUserId()

Here is the picture of the database, there might be a problem with it that i am not getting.

Here the user that contain profile pic are signed in with google and the other one is fake email address that don't exist. Let me know if i am doing something wrong in the code that don't has proper effect on this database.
and the rules are read and write "true".

[image]

Comment: So most likely `currentUserName` is `null`, right? When you want to perform the comparation.

Comment: Yes, as I have explained in detail in my question that whenever I am trying to do login with the fake(not real email) email address the app crashes and current username at this point is null, and when I launch the app again in my device (not from Android studio), it goes to main activity because login was successful, and now the current user is empty but not null. And it ignores to exclude the current user from the list so current user also display in the recyclerView list.

Comment: and when I sign in with the Google account it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I was using before:

```
if (!currentUserId.equals(users.getUserId())){
                    list.add(users);
                }
```

here I was trying to get the user ID from the user model object but it wasn't providing me the ID, and it was actually the wrong approach for me.

and this is the code that is working for me and excluding the current user from the list whether it is a real Google account or a fake email.

```
  if (!currentUserId.equals(childKey)){
                    list.add(users);
                }
```

here child key is the:

```
String childKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

This actually gives me a user id as a key in every iteration of the loop and hence I used this for comparison and it is working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
reference.addValueForSingleEventListener();
```

instead of:

```
reference.addValueEventListener();
```